# jcitest matlab normalization of cointegration vector

Tags: time-series, econometrics, cointegration

(moved this question from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936692/jcitest-matlab-interpretation-of-output))
I am using the matlab function for the Johansen test [jcitest to estimate a VECM](https://de.mathworks.com/help/econ/estimate-vec-model-parameters-using-jcitest.html). As far as I understood, the output corresponding to the cointegration vector here is the `B` stored in `paramVals in mles,` while the intercept is `c0`:

```
A(B´yt−1+c0)
```

When using the function [egcitest for the Engle-Granger test](https://de.mathworks.com/help/econ/estimate-vec-model-parameters.html), I get 1 value less for B and add a 1 to the cointegration vector, since the first coefficient is normalized to unity.
Does this mean that in the output of jcitest, the first coefficient is not normalized, but rather the first value stored in `B`?
And if so, is there any way to also normalize this cointegration vector such that the first value is 1? (My guess is to divide all coefficients by `B1`, but I am not sure whether this is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone runs into the same issue, to standardize the cointegration vector with respect to B1, you simply divide all values of the cointegration vector, as well as c0 by B1.
[This](https://de.mathworks.com/help/econ/compare-approaches-to-cointegration-analysis.html) gives an example for the above standardization. When continuing to work with the model, one then also has to adjust the alpha by multiplying it with B1. Here's a piece  of code I used to perform the standardization.

```
    BJ = mles.r1.paramVals.B;
    c0J = mles.r1.paramVals.c0;
    AJ = mles.r1.paramVals.A;

    %Normalize cointegration vector with respect to 1st variable (such that 
    beta_1 = 1)
    BJn = BJ(:,1)/BJ(1,1);
    c0Jn = c0J(1)/BJ(1,1);
    mles.r1.paramVals.B = BJn;
    mles.r1.paramVals.c0 = c0Jn;

    %Adjust alpha by multiplying with 1st variable of beta
    AJn = AJ(:,1)*BJ(1,1);
```